# Why is my Framelayout not clickable when nesting a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget, android-adapterview, android-framelayout

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="gravity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/widget_spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/widget_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/widget_spacing"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/widget_spacing" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/image_flipper"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm attaching a pending intent to it like this:

```
RemoteViews remView = new RemoteViews(ctxContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
PendingIntent pitClick = WidgetHelpers.getClickIntent(ctxContext, getKlass(), intInstance);
remView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_details, pitClick);
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctxContext).updateAppWidget(intInstance, remView);
```

If I replace the `ListView` with another view such an `AdapterViewFlipper`, it works, but, for some reason, the `ListView` doesn't correctly handle the click. When using the `ListView`, I am able to click if I very carefully click on the edges but when using the `AdapterViewFlipper` the entire thing is clickable.